# What is the best widget for inputting time in PyGTK

Tags: pygtk

I want the user to be able to input the duration for the application to be active. So my question is, what is the best widget or combination of widgets to allow the user to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Went with three spinbuttons. One for hours, minutes and seconds each.

Comment: The standard Gnome panel clock uses three spin buttons as well.